# Position fixed with 100% width of the parent DIV

Tags: css, width, fixed

My client (website - http://www.abclandscaping.com/) wanted me to make their top navigation bar be a sticky bar when the web page scrolls down.

Using JS I added .sticky class to the navigation bar (div with ID="navbar") when the scrolling happens.  The .sticky class is this:

```
    .sticky{ position: fixed;  top: 0;}
```

However, now that my navigation bar (div with ID="navbar") has fixed position its width is no longer within the parent's div and becomes 100% wide of the entire browser window. I understand why that happens, but I can't figure out how to fix the problem.

I read the other threads on this question, but none of the fixes discussed there worked for my case.

Here is my website where I'm having the issue:http://www.abclandscaping.com/

Comment: You have an additional problem, when sticky is applied "What Our Clients Say" gets partially hidden under the main logo.

You could set Left: 0; as well, but then you will have to adjust all the content of the header as well, as it al shifts.

Comment: @Kyle - yes, this is true, but it is because the Navbar div now is so wide and so its content shifts. If I figure out how to restrict its width to be no more than that of its parent then there is no overlapping and the content is placed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really getting what you want, but:

If you want `#navbar`'s width to be relative to `#masthead`:

- Make `#masthead` get the class `sticky`
- `#navbar` and `#logo` to be positioned absolute
- `.sticky #rev_slider_1_1_wrapper, .sticky #subheader {  visibility:hidden  }`

Comment: This doesn't work as  #masthead contains some elements which do need to be scrolled out of the view.